# OpenGL complains about enum usage

Tags: opengl

I've a error caught which is exactly this:

```
Source=DEBUG_SOURCE_API Type=DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR ID=3200 Severity=DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH Message=Using glGetIntegerv in a Core context with parameter <pname> and enum '0xbb1' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM)
Source=DEBUG_SOURCE_API Type=DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR ID=3200 Severity=DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH Message=Using glGetIntegerv in a Core context with parameter <pname> and enum '0xd3b' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM)
OpenGL error occured: A GLenum argument was out of range.
```

This is the first time this error appeared and first i thought that i'm using something which does not exist anymore but i found out that theese values do not even exist in my headers.

```
CLIENT_ATTRIB_STACK_DEPTH = 0xbb1
MAX_CLIENT_ATTRIB_STACK_DEPTH = 0xd3b
```

However after some additional research i found out that its even stranger than i thought because i have something in my code which stops the debugger in debug builds when a OpenGL error occured.

```
#if DEBUG
    Debug.HoldOnGLError();
#endif
```

This is inserted after every OpenGL call BUT it's not stopping at `glGetIntegerv`, its stopping at a random method mostly some `glBindBuffer`or `glBindFramebuffer`.

I've no clue why does errors appear and would be happy about any idea.

## Edit

Forgot to mention that the error is only appearing after some time and only in Debug mode in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework that could be making these calls? It might help if you can provide more details about the platform/environment/tools you are using. In any case, if the error check is triggered on your first OpenGL call, you might be able to work around it by calling `glGetError()` to clear the error state first.

Comment: Actually my own framework which works perfect the most time. It's C# with a own header. Using Windows 7, AMD R9 290. The issue is that the call appears randomly at different methods which does not make sence at all and also don't help when debugging.

Comment: Seriously, who was it who voted to close this question? This is a perfectly valid OpenGL question. It's not a "my code is not working" complaint. Guys, if you don't understand the question, or in case of doubt, just leave it. – **Upvoted because valid question on an issue other people may trip into as well, and we want them to find this and an answer if typing it into a search engine of choice.**

Comment: If you're not calling `glGetIntegerv()` much in your own code, I would try to set a debug break point on the function, and run your app in the debugger. If you look at the call stack when the break point triggers, you should be able to see where the function is called from. If it's really not anything in your code, it could be some kind of tool that got hooked into your code. For example, I've seen similar calls from trace capture tools.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I also thought about this, even thought i got a virus but it's strange that it's only appearing in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that it's not my fault. Its fault of AMD, actually **AMD-Gaming-Evolved** uses old code for its overlay, thats also the reason it crashed after some time because the overlay appears after a couple of seconds.

Exiting the client solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL debugging messages (through the callback) have been only introduced with OpenGL-4.3. The client attribute stack ([glPushClientAttrib](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushClientAttrib.xml) and friends) (which these enums are about) are functionality of OpenGL-1.1 and have been deprecated with OpenGL-3 and are only available in *compatibility* profiles. If you have a core profile context, then the relevant enums are indeed invalid to use.

Something in your program (a library or legacy code) makes use of the [client] attribute stack(s) and thereby triggers this error. You should find which part this is, because the attribute stack is being used to save and restore OpenGL state, and if the code in question relies on that to restore OpenGL state after it's done it may leave the OpenGL context in an undesired state.

The same also goes for the (server) attribute stack ([glPushAttrib](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushAttrib.xml) and friends).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As i said i don't use them and also don't use a external library. I still try to find out why this is happening. Maybe its some kind of debug functionality in the driver. Still the anwer might help others so +1.

Comment: Found out what it is, it's AMD-Gaming-Evolved.